# Will Firebase Blaze plan charge me for low testing usage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement this: https://github.com/gordonnl/firebase-stripe and it says I need to "Enable billing on your project by switching to the Blaze or Flame plan."

If I switch to the Blaze plan from the free plan will I get charged for the small amount of testing usage I have? Or does the charging only start after I go over the free plan usage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service question and not a programming question. Contact Firebase directly for information regarding their pricing and features. This site is for strictly programming-related questions.

Comment: Sorry was directed to StackOverflow from here: https://firebase.google.com/support/?authuser=0

Comment: An off-site vendor can put whatever they want on their site, but this is not their site. :-) Questions asked here must be within this site's guidelines, though. Programming questions are on topic, customer service questions are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to call non-Google APIs from Cloud Functions you need to have a billing account associated with your project. This is mostly in an effort to prevent abuse, not to actually charge you. Since Stripe is a non-Google API, you will need to have your project on a billed plan to be able to call it from Cloud Functions.

On the Blaze/pay-as-you-go plan you get the same free quota as a project on the Spark/free tier has. The exact quota are displayed on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). You will only be charged when you go beyond that free quota.